# Access data-bind="value:var" from directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I want to mimic the behavior of custom editor in **kendo-grid** but i encounter a problem on accessing the object passed on **data-bind="value:currentObjInGrid"**

I have this sample html

```
<div ng-app="TestApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <div custom-input="MyInput" data-bind="value:Hey"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and javascript

```
var app = angular.module('TestApp', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.Hey = {
                    A: 'Jude',
                    B: 'John'
                };
}]);

app.directive("customInput", function ($timeout, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "EA",
        scope: {
            customInput: '@',
            bind: '='
        },
        transclude: true,          
        template: '<button>Hi</button>',
        controller: function($scope){
            // i want to access the content of 'Hey' here 
            // as 2 way binding or pass by reference
            // but i can't access it

            console.log($scope);
        }
    }
});
```

Is this the proper way to access the object from **data-bind**?

Any help would be appreciated.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5pns023m/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use data-bind="value: Hey" because this is part of Kendo UI MVVM. It won't work with AngularJS. If you want to get the value of the bind attribute you can do it like this:

```
<div custom-input="MyInput" data-bind="Hey"></div>
```

Then use the Hey property of your $scope:

```
    controller: function($scope){
        // i want to access the content of 'Hey' here 
        // as 2 way binding or pass by reference
        // but i can't access it

        console.log($scope.bind);
    }
```

Here is a live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/EGoWu

Comment: Yeah, i can see that would work but look at this example http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/editing-custom the method categoryDropDownEditor has the element tag that has data-bind="value:xxx"